# button reversed when pressed

Tags: swift, uikit

Would like to create a button "scan" that is reversed and outlined when pressed (see image below)

Was using a button configurator (with storyboard) but am having trouble getting background color to update with isHighlighted.  Happy to switch to SwiftUI from Storyboard if necessary.

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

let scanButton = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    configButton()
    scanButton.configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
        //this transform is for testing and works
        button.transform = button.isHighlighted ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95) : .identity
        var config = button.configuration
        //changing the title works
        config?.title = button.isHighlighted ? "pressed" : "scan" 
        //config?.background = button.isHighlighted ?  //need some help
        button.configuration = config   
    }
}

func configButton(){

    scanButton.configuration = .filled()
    scanButton.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .green
    scanButton.configuration?.title = "scan"
    scanButton.configuration?.baseForegroundColor = .black

    addButtonConstraints()
}

func addButtonConstraints(){
    view.addSubview(scanButton)
    scanButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scanButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        scanButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        scanButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 125),
        scanButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
    ])
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

The button in this example was placed using Interface Builder as a `Filled Button` in `Main.storyboard`, then connected to the View Controller code with an `@IBOutlet`.  The code example is `ViewController.swift`.

The button inverts its color scheme and gains a contrasting outline when it is pressed down, then reverts to its original appearance when it is released.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Set up this outlet to allow accessing the button's layer and configuration properties
    @IBOutlet weak var swapColorsButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Set up the button's outline.  Since the button has a white background when not pressed down, the outline does not become visible until the button is pressed.
        swapColorsButton.layer.borderWidth = 3
        swapColorsButton.layer.borderColor = CGColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        swapColorsButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    }
    
    // This is a Touch Down action -- it inverts the button's colors when it is pressed
    @IBAction func pressDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
        swapColorsButton.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .black
        swapColorsButton.configuration?.baseForegroundColor = .white
    }
    // This is a Touch Up Inside action -- releasing the button resets it to its original colors
    @IBAction func buttonReleased(_ sender: UIButton) {
        swapColorsButton.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .white
        swapColorsButton.configuration?.baseForegroundColor = .black
    }
}
```

In order to detect being pressed down and released without using the `isHighlighted` property, the example code has two separate `@IBActions` controlling the color changes.  Pressing the button down is a `Touch Down` action, and releasing the button is `Touch Up Inside`.  To get the full menu of `@IBAction` options, instead of just the default one, right click on the button in `Main.storyboard`.  You can then drag and drop from the menu options to `ViewController.swift`.